# Using for-each loop in java

Tags: java

In my code,

```
for(City city : country.getCities()){
   // do some operations
}
```

Using country.getCities() is costly? Will JVM maintain the stacktrace for every call..?

```
List<City> cityList = country.getCities();
for(City city : cityList){
   // do some operations
}
```

What is the best way to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this loop:

```
for(City city : country.getCities())
```

will only call `country.getCities()` *once*, and then iterate over it. It doesn't call it for each iteration of the loop. In your case it's equivalent to:

```
for (Iterator<City> iterator = country.getCities().iterator();
     iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    City city = iterator.next();
    // do some operations
}
```

There's no benefit in rewriting it as per your second snippet.

See [section 14.14.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) for more details.

Comment: There is one benefit, writing the long version with an explicit iterator allows you to do iterator.remove() which you cannot do with the short version

Comment: @portforwardpodcast: Sure, but that's like saying it's better to use a `for` loop and `get` because then you've got the index. In the context of the code actually provided here, there's no benefit.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases the `getCities()` is called only once.

Default disclaimer: As always you hardly ever need to worry about performance, as the compiler is much better at it than a person.

Answer (score 1):

These are equivalent. `getCities()` will only be executed *once*. (if you stick a `System.out.println()` in that method you should see this).

Note that it won't call `getCities()` multiple times not just for reasons of performance, but also because there's *no guarantee that it would return the same collection each time* (it may be intuitive that it returns the same collection, but not mandated)

I would prefer your first example for conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same, there is no difference. And `country.getCities()` will be called once in loop.

I think first one better because there is no extra reference used.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will optimise the code when its compiled to ensure the `country.getCities()` method is called once.

You should write your code in the way you and/or your team think is most readable.